# How to use or operator in python for selecting multiple values from a column in a csv

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate the percentage of people who have the number 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 in one spectific column 'y', but I am getting the following error: 
**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'bool'**

This is my code:

```
All = df.shape[0]
Seizure = df[df['y'] == 1]
nonSeizure = (df[df['y'] == 2]) | (df[df['y'] == 3]) | (df[df['y'] == 4]) | (df[df['y'] == 5])

x = len(Seizure)/All
y = len(nonSeizure)/All

print('Seizure :',x*100,'%')
print('non Seizure :',y*100,'%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isin` function of the pandas dataframe to achieve the desired result.

> The isin() function is used to check each element in the DataFrame is
>   contained in values or not.

Here is the code you might want to try,

```
lst = [2, 3, 4, 5] # --> declare the list

All = df.shape[0]
Seizure = df[df['y'] == 1]
nonSeizure = df[df['y'].isin(lst)]

x = len(Seizure)/All
y = len(nonSeizure)/All

print('Seizure :',x*100,'%')
print('non Seizure :',y*100,'%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nonSeizure = df.loc[df['y'].isin([2, 3, 4, 5])]`, because it is a more pythonic way. Your code may code this way.